# What is the formula for the wavelength of radiation produced by non-relativistic electrons travelling through an undulator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electrons, microwaves

Is it simply equal to the length of the undulator periods? Or does it depend on the electrons' velocity and the strength of the magnetic field? Thanks.